# Given a Taylor polynomial of degree $2$, study if there is a saddle point at a point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

True or false? *"The Taylor polynomial of order $2$ of a field $f$ at point $(-2,1)$ is $$p(x,y)=1+\dfrac 12(^2+4xy+y^2),$$ so $f$ has in $(-2, 1)$ a saddle point."*

---

Let's take a look at the critical points of $f$: $$\nabla f(x,y)=\nabla p(x,y)=(x+2y,2x+y)\quad\Rightarrow\quad(x+2y,2x+y)=(0,0)\quad\Rightarrow\quad\begin{cases}x+2y&=0\\2x+y&=0\end{cases}\quad\Rightarrow\quad\text{The critical points are }\{(0,0)\},$$

hence $(-2,1)$ is not a critical point, hence $$\boxed{(-2,1)\quad\text{is not a saddle point}}.$$

---

**I do not know if it is correct to say that $ f $ "is equal" to $ p $**. I did exercises where the partial derivatives coincide with those of the Taylor Polynomial of order 2, but here I do not know if it is like that.

**Are my reasoning correct?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taylor expansion describes the local behavior of a function. As a result, a more rigorous way to state the result is

---

Since

$$ \left.\nabla f(x, y)\right|_{(x, y) = (-2, 1)} = \left.\nabla p(x, y)\right|_{(x, y) = (-2, 1)} = (0, -3) \neq (0, 0), $$

$(-2, 1)$ is not a critical point of $f(x, y)$, hence $(-2, 1)$ is not a saddle point.

Comment: Yay I guessed it! It makes sense now... thank you.

Comment: This is one possible interpretation of $p(x,y)$. Another plausible one in fairly wide use is that $x$ and $y$ represent *displacements* from $(-2,1)$, i.e., $p(x,y)\approx f(-2+x,1+y)$, in which case the claim is true. No way to tell without knowing the definition used by the O.P.’s course material.

Answer (score 0):

No, you may not say that $f$ is equal to $p$, though you can tell them equal *to the second order*.

From the definition of the Taylor development, you can conclude that the gradients and Hessians of $f$ and $p$ are equal at $(-2,1)$.

The gradient is indeed $0$ and the determinant of the Hessian

$$\begin{vmatrix}2&4\\4&2\end{vmatrix}$$ is negative, hence you do have a saddle point.

---

This hold iff $x$ and $y$ denote the displacements from $(-2,1)$ and not absolute coordinates.

Comment: OK, first question: How did you find the Hessian? The second partial derivatives of $f$ are $f''_{xx}=1,\;f''_{xy}=2,\;f''_{yy}=1$. I know the determinant is $<0$ too but just for ensure. Then, I know if the determinant of the Hessian is negative we, by Hessian Criteria, in $(-2,1)$ have a saddle point. So... that's all? We prove that we have a saddle point? I don't understand, and this is the 2nd question, "This hold iff $x$ and $y$ denote the displacements from $(−2,1)$ and not absolute coordinates." Thank you.